# How to prevent accepting multiple space in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to achieve to avoid user for continues hitting the space in `react-select` input. functionality should be like if user type one character or word then only single space should be accepted by `react-select` but in current situation after typing single character or word user can type or press space multiple or continuously. Is there any way in `react-select` where we can prevent the user for adding or pressing multiple space in.

any help will be appreciated.

here is screen short where `react-select` accepting multiple spaces after typing word.

[image]

Note: I know how to prevent space By using this

```
       <Select
        className="select-width select-color"
        menuPortalTarget={document.body}
        styles={customStyles}
        value={selectedVal}
        onChange={(e) => { this.onChange(e, this.props) }}
        options={technologyArray && technologyArray.map(t => ({ value: t, label: t }))}
        openMenuOnClick={true}
        placeholder="Please select tech"
        components={{ IndicatorSeparator: () => null }}
        onKeyDown={e => {
            if (e.keyCode === 32) e.preventDefault();
          }}
        />
onKeyDown={e => {
         if (e.keyCode === 32) e.preventDefault();
    }}
```

but I want to prevent multiple space or continues space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onInputChange` prop to control `inputValue` which is visible to user.

```
 onInputValueChange = inputValue => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: this.allowOnlyOneSpace(inputValue) });
  };

  allowOnlyOneSpace = str => {
    return str.endsWith(" ") ? str.trim() + " " : str.trim();
  };
```

Above code will allow one space given that option may contain some value with space e.g. "A and B"

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-qwbo1?file=/example.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use onInputChange props to clear it.

```
  handleInputChange = (newValue: string) => {
    const inputValue = newValue.replace(/\W/g, '');
    this.setState({ inputValue });
    return inputValue;
  };

   <Select
    onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
   />
```

Comment: No problem, up it if you want :)